# Express XOR in SKI combinators

Tags: haskell, combinatory-logic

I am trying to solve [sure but can you SKI](https://www.codewars.com/kata/sure-but-can-you-ski-i) on codewars. It is about to express lambda in SKI combinators. Source is at https://repl.it/@delta4d/SKI.

After some researching, especially the [Combinatory Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis), I am able to solve all the cases except `xor`.

I first translates xor into

```
xor x y = if y 
          then if x
               then false
               else true
          else x
```

which is

```
xor = \x y -> y (x false true) x
-- false = K I
-- true = K
```

applying lambda to SKI rules, I got

```
\x.\y.y (x false true) x
\x.S (\y.y (x false true)) (K x)
\x.S (S I (K (x false true))) (K x)
S (\x.S (S I (K (x false true)))) K
S (S (K S) (\x.S I (K (x false true)))) K
S (S (K S) (S (K (S I)) (\x.K (x false true)))) K
S (S (K S) (S (K (S I)) (S (K K) (\x.x false true)))) K
S (S (K S) (S (K (S I)) (S (K K) (S (\x.x false) (K true))))) K
S (S (K S) (S (K (S I)) (S (K K) (S (S I (K false)) (K true))))) K
```

I have checked the SKI presentation on http://ski.aditsu.net, it works fine.

Haskell sources compiles, but got runtime error.

Codewars reports:

> ```
> Couldn't match type `a' with `Bool' a'
>   `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
>       a type expected by the context: a -> a -> a at Kata.hs:66:9
> Expected type: SKI
>                  (Bool' a -> (Bool' a -> Bool' a -> Bool' a) -> a -> a -> a)
>   Actual type: SKI (Bool' (Bool' a))
> In the second argument of `xorF', namely `true'
> In the second argument of `($)', namely `xorF true true'
> ```

I have test on local with `prettyPrintSKI $ Ap (Ap xor' false) true`, and it reports:

> ```
> • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a20 ~ Bool' a20
>   Expected type: SKI
>                    (Bool' a20 -> (Bool' a20 -> Bool' a20 -> Bool' a20) -> Bool' a20)
>     Actual type: SKI (Bool' (Bool' a20))
> • In the second argument of ‘Ap’, namely ‘true’
>   In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘Ap (Ap xor' false) true’
>   In the expression: prettyPrintSKI $ Ap (Ap xor' false) true
> ```

What is the infinite type about? what is the rigid type?

I am doing the same thing on `or` as `or = \x y -> x true y`, and it works just fine.

---

1. https://www.codewars.com/kata/sure-but-can-you-ski-i
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic
3. http://ski.aditsu.net

Comment: In Haskell `True` and `False` are constructors, hence you should use an uppercase, or in case you want the lambda variant, then you can not use an `if`, but then you should call the functions.

Comment: Can you share your exact implementation?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, here `true` and `false` is not the same in Haskell. It defines as `false = Ap K I`, `true = K`. My intention of using `if then else` has nothing to do with Haskell, just pseudo code. You can  see the problem on codewars for more info.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem https://repl.it/@delta4d/SKI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the double use of `x` in `λxy.y (x false true) x`. It's forced to have two types simultaneously. Since `y` uses `x`, `y` must return something of let's say type `a`. Now this means that `x false true` is also of type `a`. So something of type `a` must be `(b -> b -> a)` (for some `b`). But that's impossible, since that means `a` must contain itself.

It's worth noting that your solution is correct wrt. SK, just not Haskell's type system. So to fix we need to not use `x` twice with different types. So why not make them the same type with `λxy.y(x false true)(x true false)`?

Comment: I guess that if `x` has a polymorphic type `forall a. a->a->a` then that code could be compiled. This requires higher rank types, and turning on the suitable Haskell extensions.